# Product Config Wizard in farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, psconfig

I have 2 Web and 2 App servers in production farm. (+ separate database server)
After patching/security updates I would like to run Configuration Wizard.
What is the serial I should follow?
both App first and then Web?

Answer (score 0):

Important sentence in advance: Run Configuration Wizard only on one server. Do not run it in parallel on multiple servers!

1. Begin with application server which runs the CentralAdministration site
2. Continue with second application server
3. Run it on the web servers
4. [Verify upgrade](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493323(v=office.16).aspx)

Reference: [Install a software update for SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/72addaae-efe5-40bb-8c86-294e10266878(v=office.16).aspx)